# How to make an int counter for the days

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdate

How would you go about making an int variable lets say "counter" that increments itself as by 1 for each day that goes by in objective C. Having trouble implementing this, most sources I saw online suggested finding the difference in two NSDates but this isn't what I was going for. Any suggestions, please and thank you.

Comment: @OP : is your app based on webservice? if yes, get current and compare date from webservice...

Comment: Your question has (currently) a -2 score, this should suggest to you it needs improvement. Can you give more details on what you are actually trying to achieve, and what you have tried to accomplish it? Are you trying to count the number of consecutive 24 hour periods your app is continuously running? Are you trying to count the number of distinct calendar days you app has been run? Etc. You've said you having trouble implementing what you need, but you don't show anything you've tried. Give these details and maybe somebody can help. (Edit the question to add details, don't put it in comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the below mentioned steps to find the counter you are looking for

1. Create an NSDate Object currentDate
2. Get the current time from **[currentDate timeIntervalSince1970]**, this will return you the current time in UTC since 1970 thus eliminating any effect of changing the date on your device since you cannot go behind 1970. Tried on my iPhone
3. Save this time in NSUserDefaults as the time your startTime, will be helpful if your application goes into the background or is terminated
4. Schedule a 24 hours timer using the **NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval** function, it will increment the counter by one
5. Once the counter is incremented, restart the timer so that it updates the counter again after 24 hours
6. If your application was terminated or became inactive due to which the NSTimer stops, you can always update the counter by finding the difference in seconds between the current time (follow step # 1 and 2) and the time you saved in NSUserDefaults and converting that into days, also resetting the timer accordingly so that it can increment the counter accordingly

Hope this solves you problem.

Comment: How does (2) eliminate any effect of changing the date on the device? (The OP hasn't mentioned pushing the clock back, but both answers at the moment seem to assume this might be need to be handled.)

Comment: (2) is to eliminate the date change effect if NSDate is used as mentioned in the first answer. You are right the OP has not mentioned pushing the clock back, but it will be good if this scenairo is covered.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get NSDateComponents from two dates.  Say you've recorded `startDate` when the day counter should start, then ...

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:startDate
                                             toDate:[NSDate date]  // this is "now"
                                            options:0];
```

will give you a date components object that can answer....

```
NSInteger day = [components day];
```

with the number of days between `startDate` and now.

Comment: It is not good to take [NSDate date], since user can change this date in his device. Thus the day calculation will go wrong.

Comment: True.  I just saw "Interstellar", and should point out that this solution also fails near the edges of black holes.